# Python Code not running in Zapier

Tags: python, zapier

I am getting a very blank error from Zapier when I try and test my code.

Zapier, unfortunately, is not giving me any kind of error code, just a:

Bargle. We hit an error creating a run python. :-( Error: 
Your code had an error!

I am very rusty with Python and I am wondering if anyone can help me diagnose my code.

```
URLList{
'Prod1':'a URL',
'Prod2':'a Different URL'
}

ProductNames{
'Prod1':'Prod1 Name',
'Prod2':'Prod2 Name'
};

links{};

## Go through the Dictionary of requested 
for k, v in input_data.iteritems():
    if v != null:
        input_data[k] = URLList[k];
    else:
        del input_data[k];

for k, v in input_data.iteritems():
    links[k] = '<p><a href="'+ URLList[k] +'">' + ProductNames[k] +'</p>';

string EmailText = "";
for k, v in links:
    EmailText = links[k] + '<br />';
return(EmailText);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The bad news is that most of your Python statements are syntactically invalid. I'm not sure if this is something you're still working on, but I'd give [this cheatsheet](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/python/) a once-over. The good news is that most of the fixes are pretty straightforwards (you're missing a lot of `=` and using semi-colons (which Python doesn't use)) and once fixed, it seems like your code will work as you expect.

​Let me know if you've got any specific questions!